# Django, mozilla-django-oidc and admin

Tags: django, openid-connect, okta

i am trying to connect Okta with a custom Django (v.3.0.2) app i am coding, using the [mozilla-django-oidc](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc) library. So far the initial user authentication and account creation (using Django's [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/)) works, but i don't understand what i need to do to have the Django [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) work.

The Adminsite, before introducing `mozilla-django-oidc` worked as expected. I created an admin user, named "admin" and the user was able to login.

To integrate the `mozilla-django-oidc` library i followed the instructions here: https://mozilla-django-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html. The instructions do not have any specific mention of the AdminSite.

When i access the AdminSite after the library integration, i have the following:

1. The AdminSite uses the default template - my assumption was that it
   would also use Okta to authenticate.
2. The admin account "admin" that used to be able to login into the AdminSite does not work anymore

My goal is to be able to access the AdminSite. I don't mind if it will be over Okta or over the vanilla interface as long as i can access it.

Below are the relevant segments from the files (in order to integrate):

---

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', static_site.site_index, name='site_index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('review/', include('review.urls')),
    path('oidc/', include('mozilla_django_oidc.urls')),
]
```

---

settings.py

```
# OICD
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mozilla_django_oidc.auth.OIDCAuthenticationBackend',
)

OIDC_RP_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxx'
OIDC_RP_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxx'
OIDC_RP_SIGN_ALGO = 'RS256'
OIDC_OP_JWKS_ENDPOINT = 'https://dev-xxx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys'
OIDC_RP_SCOPES = 'openid email profile'

OIDC_OP_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://dev-xxx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize'
OIDC_OP_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'https://dev-xxx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token'
OIDC_OP_USER_ENDPOINT = 'https://dev-xxx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo'

# Provided by mozilla-django-oidc
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('oidc_authentication_callback')

# App urls
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('review:dashboard')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('site_index')
```

Any ideas or pointers welcomed!

Answer (score 4):

The goal was achieved by adding the default auth backend to the settings:

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'mozilla_django_oidc.auth.OIDCAuthenticationBackend',
]
```

I don't get Okta auth for the admin, but since i am happy just to have the admin running, i will stop here.

Comment: I am having issue while authenticating the user. Once the user is authenticated it  gives me SuspiciousOperation at /oidc/callback/ error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

I've come up with a solution for using the mozilla-django-oidc login with the django admin. It's a little hacky but it's a lot less intimidating to redirect the admin login page than to override AdminSite.

In my top-level urls.py I have

```
class CustomLogin(View):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('oidc_authentication_init') + (
                '?next={}'.format(request.GET['next']) if 'next' in request.GET else ''
            )
        )

urlpatterns = [
    path('oidc/', include("mozilla_django_oidc.urls")),
    path('admin/login/', CustomLogin.as_view()),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # the rest of my urls...
]
```

---

If you don't care about passing the `?next=` value correctly you can skip the CustomLogin class and do the following instead

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('oidc/', include("mozilla_django_oidc.urls")),
]
# This only works if you break up urlpatterns so the reverse below can find what it needs
urlpatterns += [
    path('admin/login/', RedirectView.as_view(
        url=reverse('oidc_authentication_init') + ?next=/admin/,
        permanent=False
    )),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # the rest of my urls...
]
```

I added `?next=/admin/` because by default once you log in you will be redirected to `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` which I'm already using for something else

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default primary identifier, "email", you can create a superuser with that same email which will give SU privileges to that SSO user. So for example, if you have an SSOuser with email testuser@example.com, you can then run `python manage.py createsuperuser` and when prompted, set the email to testuser@example.com; the username and password don't matter since you're not actually using them for authentication (if you remove `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` from `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`). I currently have this working, although I am extending the mozilla backend with the steps recommended in https://mozilla-django-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#connecting-oidc-user-identities-to-django-users to prevent users from being created on the fly.